# Help with Jacobi's formula

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that

$$
\frac d{dt}\left( \det e^\mathbf {At}\right)= \text{Tr}\left(\mathbf A \right)\det e^\mathbf {At}\ ,
$$
I have to use Jacobi's formula $
\frac d{dt}\left( \det \mathbf A\right)H= \text{Tr}\left( \text{adj} (\mathbf A ) H\right)\ ,
$
but I need some hints.

Also, is there an easy way to understand how the formula
$
\det\left( e^{\mathbf A} \right) = e^{\text{Tr}(\mathbf A)}\ 
$  works? How is this formula derived?

Comment: hint: $det(B)=\prod \lambda(B)_i$ and $Tr(C)=\sum \lambda(C)_i$ where $\lambda(X)_i$ is the $i$'th eigenvalue of $X$

Comment: No need for the Jacobi formula. Just note that for 
$$
f(t) = \det \exp(At) = \exp(\operatorname{tr}(At)),
$$
we can apply the chain rule:
$$
f'(t) = \exp(\operatorname{tr}(e^{At})) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{tr}(At).
$$

Comment: @user619894 Thanks I see the second formula now

Comment: The usual proof of the formula is as follows: first show that it holds for diagonal/diagonalizable matrices, then use limits of sequences and continuity to handle the general case.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I thought about the chain rule, but I don't see how $exp(tr(e^{At}))⋅\frac{d}{dt}tr(e^{At})$ is $\text{Tr}\left(\mathbf A \right)\det e^\mathbf {At}$

Comment: @Hyewon I had a bit of a typo when I typed that earlier, see the current version

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Comparing it side by side I see it now :) Thanks so much xP